# Clarification on what this exception means

Tags: c#

I have a C# DLL that is being invoked on a users computer.

They have Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed and yet my logging software is raising this issue:

```
<LogEntry Date="2017-03-12 12:06:15" Severity="Exception" Source="MSAToolsLibrary.MSAToolsLibraryClass.UpgradeDatabase" ThreadId="1">
  <Exception Type="System.NullReferenceException" Source="MSAToolsLibrary.MSAToolsLibraryClass.UpgradeDatabase">
    <Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message>
    <StackTrace>   at MSAToolsLibrary.MSAToolsLibraryClass.UpgradeDatabase()</StackTrace>
  </Exception>
</LogEntry>
```

Does this mean that the actual MSAToolLibrary object has not been correctly registered on their computer or is it more directed to the UpgradeDatabase method itself?

Comment: the method itself, but without breakpoints i can't see how you're gonna catch that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception states that it originated within the method `MSAToolsLibrary.MSAToolsLibraryClass.UpgradeDatabase()`. So there is some line in that method which causes a `NullReferenceException`

The below code will demonstrate how it works

```
static string Foo(object arg) {
    return arg.ToString(); // Line 2
}

static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(Foo(null)); // Line 6
}
```

**Output:**

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at Program.Foo(Object arg) in Program.cs:line 2
>   at Program.Main() in Program.cs:line 6